# Searching Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

I have seen a lot of ventures adding assets to the blockchain, eg land titles, art titles, insurance policies and many more. But how are these ever found? There is no SQL or JSON to search the blockchain.

How can someone find something on the blockchain by just knowing its content?

I mean something like:

```
select * from autoparts where carmaker = 'Ford'
```

Answer (score 1):

The ethereum blockchain uses LevelDb (not Sqllite) you could explore it using levelup with nodejs like described in this [post](http://wanderer.github.io/ethereum/nodejs/code/2014/05/21/using-ethereums-tries-with-node/).